# getAttributeText() use default value regardless what store view the user is on

Tags: product-attribute, store-view

How would I go about getting the Admin value for an attribute, regardless of the visitor's chosen store view?

I've tried:
`$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_condition = $_product->getAttributeText('condition');
$_conditionDefault = $_product->setStoreID(0)->getAttributeText('condition');`

However, setStoreId() does not work in this context.

Regardless of the language or store view that the visitor is currently viewing, I would like to be able to output the value for the Admin Store View **and** the value for the User's Current Store View.

The Condition attribute is a DropDown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It typo mistake it should be `setStoreId` instead of `setStoreID` and use  -`getResource()`

```
$_condition = $_product->getAttributeText('condition');
$prod= $_product->setStoreId(0);
$_coditionDefault =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('condition')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and I got an error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::getAttributeText() in /app/design/frontend/sm_market/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml on line 42

Comment: Just  remove get resource()

Comment: I tried that too with no luck. Both $_condition and $_conditionDefault are outputting the same value, which is the value of the current store view. I still can't get it to output the value for Admin Store View. Any other ways it might work?

Comment: update answer.. please check

Comment: @AmitBera, pls help on this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210021/image-import-gets-stuck-in-magento-on-live-server

Answer (score 13):

Thank you very much Amit Bera. Based on the very helpful suggestions, here is the working code!

```
$_condition = $_product->getAttributeText('condition');
$_coditionDefault = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('condition')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: Excellent! Happy to confirm this works on Magento 2.1.7

Comment: For further readers, this solutions works for Magento version 2.3.5. Note that the above solution (the marked and valie) seems to be oriented to Magento 1.