# Image import gets stuck in Magento on live server

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I have successfully imported 3374 products in Magento without images in my local system through a product CSV-file (this CSV-file has all information of product corresponding to each sku *except images*).

Then I have tried the same procedure successfully in my live server.

But when I am trying to import 3374 images of product (each product has one image) in live server using image CSV-file (this CSV-file *has image* information corresponding to each sku) only some images get imported, i.e. around 300 images get imported.

Though, in my local system, I have successfully imported all 3374 images using same image CSV-file.

I don't know what happened to the Magento setup on the live server. Did anyone face the same problem?
Got stuck, please help.

Comment: Does the import get completed or do you receive any errors? Did you double check the image's source - are all located at where they are fetched from?

Comment: i did'nt receive any error,  i am using system->import functionality in magento

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125769/how-can-i-solve-image-import-not-working-after-hosting-its-good-working-in-local - maybe one of these approaches help you?

Comment: Use magmi, easy and fast way